# How can I improve my questions or how to get more attention for my questions?

Tags: support, questions

I have posted a question on Stack Overflow long ago. But I didn't get any answer yet, not even a single comment. I have added the necessary tags too. How can I improve my questions or how can I get more attention for my questions?

And one more thing, when I posted this question (How to get more attention to my questions???) on Stack Overflow, I got negative votes within seconds and somebody commented that I should post this on Meta. I am asking this to get an answer for my question and to know how to improve questions in the future. But why did I suddenly get negative voting? I am only aware of this meta just now. I am not an expert, just a beginner on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can anyone else find if this question has been asked before? I'm trying to look around on MSO, but I haven't found anything yet. Maybe the other questions were deleted? That tends to happen with these kind of questions too often `:P` This gets asked way too often, we should just have a community wiki FAQ for this so we can just start closing new ones as duplicates right away.

Comment: How long ago did you post your question? Is it [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879215/do-i-need-app-approval-from-facebook-to-posting-to-our-own-feed-from-android-app)? The one that you posted **just one hour ago**?

Comment: asked Sep 17 '13 at 18:32, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857312/android-expandablelistview-using-cursortreeadaptor

Comment: You may just have inadvertently called the [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) upon yourself...

Comment: Now I got a negative vote for my past question that was not getting any attention yet :). I think its better to keep quite and just search in Google and stack overflow for better questions and answers :(

Comment: @DennisMathew your question on Stack Overflow is a giant wall of text. Can you at least try breaking it up into smaller paragraphs so that it's easier to read?

Comment: ok, Sure @Cupcake

Comment: @DennisMathew I'm sorry, I didn't mean for that to sound like an order. It was supposed to be a suggestion. If you want to improve your question, I would start from there.

Comment: I tried to improve your question. Feel free to edit it again. Also, putting some codes may help.

Comment: Thanks @Cupcake, I took only in the right sense :)

Comment: I **think** I understand the question. To do anything about it, I would have to write a test program. Maybe an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) would help.

Comment: See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### How to get more attention for your question

If your question has not received much attention, it may be because your question is unclear, or it does not contain enough information to solve it. You can try clarifying your question to make it easier to understand, or add more information that will help other people solve it.

Alternatively, you can also post a bounty on your question to help draw extra attention to it for a week.

The above two options *do not guarantee that you'll receive an answer*. Stack Overflow receives a staggering [**7000-8000 *new* questions *per day***](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday), so some questions just go completely unanswered.

### Downvotes on Stack Overflow

The reason why you got downvotes for posting this question on Stack Overflow is because this kind of question is **off-topic** there. Stack Overflow is for, generally speaking, **programming** problems.

This question is not a programming problem, it's a question about how to use features of Stack Overflow itself, in this case, drawing more attention to a question. Thus, the question belongs here on Meta, which is for questions about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit the question to improve it, add any more information you have about the problem. This will bump it to the home page again and get you some more views. Don't do this continually though as it smacks of gaming the system.
2. Make sure your question is tagged correctly. If it doesn't have the appropriate tags or if the tags don't match the content people won't find your question and when they do they'll be put off answering it.
3. Promote the question elsewhere on the web - Twitter, Google+, Facebook or where ever you can find topic experts.

For more information see the help centre page [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)