# Can I ask the same question twice?

Tags: support, questions

This is a dumb question. I wanted to know if I can ask the same question twice or would that be breaking the rules?  I asked a question today, and I couldn't get an answer that would solve my problem, so can I ask it tomorrow?  I just don't want to be classified as a troll.

Comment: No, don't re-post - that will not end well for you. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266338/how-can-i-improve-my-questions-or-how-to-get-more-attention-to-my-questions

Comment: Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)